# What is the minimum number of a valid B+tree?

Tags: database, tree, b-tree

I'm trying to appeal on a question I had on my exam the other day,  about a B+tree.

The question was:

Consider a B+tree with l as factor (assuming l is positive and even), h>=0 as height (the root is considerto be 0) and n>=1 as the number of records.

There were 5 answers. 3 of them I eliminated immediately, and had to choose between these two:

1. `h>1  ==> n >= 0.5*l*(l+1)`. The second direction is not guaranteed: it depends on the arrival order of the keys.
2. None of the above.

I chose (2) and the lecturer says its option (1). I have the following example that I think contradicts it:

> ```
>                       7
>                /              \
>               3                9
>            /     \           /   \
>         1 2      3 4 5     7 8    9 10
> ```

With `l=4`, and `h=2`:

- Does this b+tree represent a valid B+tree?
- Is my lecturer actually wrong?

I would really appreciate some help here. Is this example a good one to base my appeal on?

In general, what is the minimum number of records `n` in a B+tree with height `h` and factor `l`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Using lower-case ell as a symbol is icky; it is difficult to distinguish from upper-case I in sans serif fonts.  'The second direction' is unusual English; did you (or the lecturer) mean 'second condition'?  Why would the B+ Tree shown not be a valid B+ Tree?  (A possible answer is 'because the root node doesn't meet the normal requirements that there are between `l/2` and `l` nodes in it (when `n >= l/2`), but then why didn't you suggest that?)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As far as I know, the root node in my example does(!) meet the normal requirements. It has 2 childs (`l=4` so `l/2` is good)
The B+ Tree shown is not part of the question, it is my way of trying to proove the lecturer's mistake.
'The second direction' means: 'Assumin A gives us B, but assuming B does'nt necessarily gives us A'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently I was right...
The tree I showed is legal and is contrasting the lecturer's answer.

By inserting the following keys in that order: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` and then taking `6` out of the tree will create a valid B+tree of `height > 1` and `n<10`.

This contradicts the `h>1 ==>    n >= 0.5*l*(l+1)` rule in the answer...

After many tries and lots of bureaucracy the lecturer accepted my answer and I got the points :)

Thanks for the try @Jonathan Leffler...